# Axaj + Render Django

Tags: ajax, django

новичок в django. Есть ajax запрос:

```
function log_in() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
        })
    }
```

так же есть html шаблон:

```
{% if log_in %}
    <h1>Hello</h1>
{% else %}
    <input type="button" value="Войти" onclick="log_in()">
{% endif %}
```

и есть обработчик:

```
def index(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
       return render(request, 'index.html', {'log_in': True})
   return render(request, 'index.html', {'log_in': False})
```

Ничего не происходит. Где я не прав?

Comment: а что должно происходить?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 он должен передавать значение log_in в шаблон

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0  Есть ли вариант передать из success в условие if?